# Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer not working well with xUnit

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I've just installed Visual Studio 2019 Professional and I noticed some misbehavior if I compare it to the VS 2017 which I used to work with.

**The Test Explorer window**

1. In the VS 2017 when I open a project, that already had been opened previously, I see all the tests in the Test Explorer. In the VS 2019 the window is empty until I rebuild the solution.
2. If I rebuild the solution and all the xUnit tests are discovered I cannot click on any single test. I can click on all the folders in the hierarchy, but not on the leaf node with the actual test - so I don't see the exception if the test fails or any further details. If I right-click on the test, the possibility Open Test is always disabled.

[image]

In VS 2017 the same solution is working fine without any changes.

Comment: (No time to investigate) but I have xUnit tests running here in VS2019, other team members have them working in VS2017.

Comment: @Richard The xUnit tests themselves are running fine, but the UI is somehow buggy. I switched back to VS2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By updating the VS the problem disappeared. I am currently running the VS 2019 Pro 16.3.6.

Comment: I have similar issue (old tests cases that were updated shows under unknown project), I am on VS Enterprise 2019 16.4.5, below are pkgs

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">

Comment: Updating VS worked for me too, although I had the problem with a much newer version.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue,

current workaround :

1. close all visual studio instances
2. delete .vs folder at project root
3. reopen the sln
4. rebuild
5. use test explorer to run tests

[Reported issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/917638/testcontainer-was-not-found.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had both VS 2017 and VS 2019 installed when I had this issue. Tests worked fine in 2017 but not in 2019. I uninstalled 2017 as it worked for others in my team who just had 2019. As soon as I uninstalled 2017 and did a restart the tests started working for me again.