# Test Explorer cannot discover any unit tests in VS2019

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, xunit

I have .NET core unit test projects which use **xunit** package in Visual studio 2019, but I found that the unit tests cannot be discovered in the Test Exporer window, and there is below info in the Output-> Test pane.

I have tried the below workaround (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682824/visual-studio-2019-test-explorer-not-working-well-with-xunit)) but none of them works

- Update the VS2019 to the latest version (my version is 16.8.3)
- Delete .vs folder then rebuild

Does anybody have any idea on this?

```
Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.TransationLayerException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.CLR.AnyCPU\ServiceHub.TestWindowStoreHost.exe process failed to connect to vstest.console process after 90 seconds. This may occur due to machine slowness, please set environment variable VSTEST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to increase timeout.
   at Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper.WaitForConnection()
   at Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper.EnsureInitialized()
   at Microsoft.TestPlatform.VsTestConsole.TranslationLayer.VsTestConsoleWrapper.InitializeExtensions(IEnumerable`1 pathToAdditionalExtensions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Messaging.RemoteAgent.BaseTestAgentBridge.InitializeExtensionsAsync(IEnumerable`1 extensions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Host.TestPlatformAgentPool.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<<CreateRemoteAgentAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Utilities.EventPumpExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<<EnqueueAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Host.TestPlatformProvider.<UpdateRuntimeEnvironmentsAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ILoggerExtensions.<CallWithCatchAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```